# Are "brim" and "rim" related in etymology?

Tags: prefixes

Are "brim" and "rim" related in etymology?

I remember there are some other words which have similar meanings after adding "b-" in their fronts. It seems as if "b-" is a prefix.

But I can't recall them right now.

Answer (score 4):

Looking in the OED, we see several entries for *brim*, of which the first two are.

1. "An old poetical word for the sea", Middle English *brymme*, Old English *brim* surf, (poet.) the sea = Old Norse *brim* surf, sea; probably < the stem *brem-* roar, rage:
2. The border, margin, edge, or brink: Middle English *brimme*, *brymme*, of uncertain etymology.

Reading the definition for (2), ME *brymme* originally meant the edge of some *water*.

There's a possible etymology staring us in the face: *surf* → *shore* → *edge*. One wonders why the OED editors didn't suggest this as a possibility.

If this etymology is correct, it seems unlikely *brim* came from the same root as *rim*, which meant *edge* when *brim* meant *surf*. It's possible that the similarity in pronunciation was a factor in the convergence of their meanings, although this is a conjecture which there is no way to provide evidence for.

Comment: The OED editors must have considered the suggestion you're making, and discarded it. One reason is no doubt the possible cognates they mention for brim(2), all of which mean "edge", not "sea".

Comment: I think it's unlikely that the Middle English word *brim*, meaning *sea, surf* had no influence on the later Middle English word *brim*, meaning *shore, coast, edge of the sea*. But it's certainly possible that the word was also influenced by another root as well; the OED says "compare Old Norse *barmr* brim, German *bräme* feminine ‘margin, border, fringe’, Middle High German *brem* strong neuter ‘edging, border’."

Answer (score 2):

Not known, but unlikely.

The OED gives many cognates to *rim* in Germanic, but does not trace it beyond that; and says that the etymology of *brim* is unknown, though it suggests a few words in other Germanic languages which might be cognate.

However, I really don't believe in *b-* as a prefix: I know of no other non-syllabic prefixes in English or in Germanic in general.